# IONIC No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I try lunch ionic from broser with ionic serve, when i try login in my project it have error when call **HTTP GET**. Error like this

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.1:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I already input HTTP ORIGIN in my **api.php** like this

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
```

I don't know why i still have error acces control allow origin, if anyone know ho to solved this problem it really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Please check http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: check your headers if the response has these headers or not. if not the problem can be with your php server code instead of ionic.

Comment: Do you allow your app to navigate outside of its domain? `<allow-navigation href="xxx" />`

Comment: @AshishDetroja i already read but it not work for me

Comment: @chowmean i check header in my webservice but still have error

Comment: @Zooly i'm not use <allow-navigation href="xxx" /> but i use http get

Comment: @RizkaNugroho I mean in your config.xml file

Answer (score 0):

**Points of reference**

See ionic.project for configuring the proxy server. Notice how we set the path to /api - signifying any request to the Ionic server http://localhost:8100/api will retrieve requests to the proxyUrl at http://localhost:3000/api/endpoint.

See `www/js/app.js` for setting up the Api Endpoint as an AngularJS constant. Notice here the address is pointed at the Ionic server.

See `www/js/services.js` for using the AngularJS constant.

See `www/js/controllers.js` for using the AngularJS service.

See `gulpfile.js` to see how the gulp tasks are set up to replace your URL's in your files.

**Getting started**

Run the following commands, the last two may require another `console/terminal` window:

```
npm install npm nodeserver npm ionicserver
```

**Reference** : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-proxy-example/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score -1):

Try it with chrome: c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:\chrome"

The important is the disable web security.